# Corner radius for a button to align with a view below

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners, swift3

There are tons of answers on SO for rounding a particular corner. The issue I'm running into is I'm trying to align a button corner to a rounded corner of the view below. Please see the image. The yellow view is rounded in 4 corners. I'm trying to get the close button to round off at top right to align with the yellow view's round corner. I've used the Swift 3 code below, but the button stays square. Can anyone please point out what is missing?

viewRaised is the yellow view.

Many thanks!

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: btnCancel.layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height:  10))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
btnCancel.layer.mask = maskLayer
btnCancel.layer.masksToBounds = true

self.viewRaised.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.viewRaised.layer.masksToBounds = false
self.viewRaised.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10);
self.viewRaised.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
self.viewRaised.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Interesting thing is that the same code seems to be working but only for top left. See the second image.

```
    self.viewRaised.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.viewRaised.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.viewRaised.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 10);
    self.viewRaised.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
    self.viewRaised.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: btnCancel.layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.allCorners], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height:  10))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
    btnCancel.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

This is quite perplexing. I'm using XCode Version 8.0 beta 6 (8S201h)

[image]

Comment: Did you try to clip to subviews?

Comment: If the button is a subview of the yellow view, it should be working by it's own. You shouldn't have to do anything.

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa If OP is setting a `layer mask`, they don't need to enable `clipsToBounds`. Also, @Nikita , setting the the button as a `subview` of its `layer mask` would cause a crash.

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa - yes tried that. Not working.

Comment: @NikitaP - the yellow view and the button are added via story board to the main view. They show the hierarchy in the Outline view. However, it is not working.

Comment: .allCorners works but only on top left. See second image. The code is same as the first case except for byRoundingCorners parameter.

Comment: Don't make a new path to set as a `layer.mask`. Your `viewRaised` should be the mask for your `btnCancel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was remove the whole of this. But it worked if I remove the bolded line only. But the rest of the lines were not needed once since Cancel Button was the subview of the yellow view.

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: btnCancel.layer.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.topRight, .bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height:  10))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
btnCancel.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

**btnCancel.layer.masksToBounds = true**

Answer (score 2):

1. Your `btnCancel.layer.mask` should be set to the **yellow view**.
2. You need to add `btnCancel` as a sublayer of of **yellow view's parent**.

**Example (Swift 3.x) :**

```
let yellowView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 200.0, 200.0))
yellowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
yellowView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
yellowView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
yellowView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
self.view.addSubview(yellowView)  // Add yellowView to self's main view
    
let btnCancel = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 45.0, 45.0))
btnCancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
btnCancel.layer.mask = yellowView.layer  // Set btnCancel.layer.mask to yellowView.layer
self.view.addSubview(btnCancel)  // Add btnCancel to self's main view, NOT yellowView
```

**NOTE:**

> You don't need to enable `clipsToBounds` because you're setting a mask layer.
>
> You Also don't need to create a new `CAShapeLayer` for the mask. Use `yellowView`'s layer as the mask.

**Swift 4.x :**

```
let yellowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 20.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
yellowView.backgroundColor = .yellow
yellowView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
yellowView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
yellowView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
self.view.addSubview(yellowView)  // Add yellowView to self's main view

let btnCancel = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 20.0, width: 45.0, height: 45.0))
btnCancel.backgroundColor = .red
btnCancel.layer.mask = yellowView.layer  // Set btnCancel.layer.mask to yellowView.layer
self.view.addSubview(btnCancel)  // Add btnCancel to self's main view, NOT yellowView
```

Comment: Thanks ZGski. How does this change if the views (both yellow and button) are added via storyboard to the main view, i.e., there is no addSubview.

Comment: I added this to the code btnCancel.layer.mask = self.viewRaised.layer and it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to make sure your `btnCancel` _is not_ a `subview` of your yellow view, but a `subview` of the yellow view's parent.

Comment: Can you please check my update above. Meanwhile I'll try your suggestion. Update: I did try that, but it keeps only rounding top left corner.